# "A New World Record" (ELO) - a pun?

Tags: album-title

The title of ELO's 1976 album, ***A New World Record***, means...

1. a new (record-breaking) achievement (a world record)
2. an album not to be confused with the contemporaneous *World Record* (Van der Graaf Generator)
3. an album for the USA, the 'New World' (as European's call(ed) it - notably, in this context, Dvorak, of New World Symphony fame)

Something else...?

Comment: It could also be "a record for (or promoting) a different kind of world". There are a couple of songs where this sort of makes sense (notably *Mission (A World Record)*.)  But yes, definitely, and obviously, a pun.

Answer (score -1):

For sure. Punsters from the very start. We need look no further than their eponymous debut album to realize that the band name itself is a pun.

Does "Electric Light Orchestra" mean

1. A light orchestra that adds electric guitars and suchlike to traditional orchestral instruments, or
2. An orchestra named after electric light?

Comment: I find the conclusion based on the band name example not exactly compelling.

Comment: Or (an) *electric* Light Orchestra (electric in the sense of having or producing a sudden sense of thrilling excitement ("the atmosphere was electric"))